# VBA to Call Sub If Text in Range is Found

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that calls on various private subs I have. I want to call a sub if a certain country name is found in the range. My range is listed in a table named 'Info table' in Column D. I will need the sub to run through each country, not stop after the first match. I have code in the private subs to verify what to do, just calling them based on the range criteria is something I am struggling with.

I assume I need some sort of If "Brazil" Then call... ElseIf "China" Then call...

Also, what kind of error handling do i need if the first country doesnt appear, I dont want the macro to stop running, need it to loop through all the countries. (I gave two as an example, there will be about 20)

Really appreciate the time and effort of all the contributors here!

```
Sub Send_Email()

Dim Country As Range

Set Country = Worksheets("Info Table").Range("D3:D30").Text.Find("Brazil")
    Call Email_Brazil

Set Country = Worksheets("Info Table").Range("D3:D30").Text.Find("China")
    Call Email_China

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Sub Send_Email()

Dim country As String
Dim yourWorksheet As Worksheet
Set yourWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Info Table") 

For j = 3 To 30

    country = yourWorksheet.Range("D" & j)

    Select Case country

        Case "Brazil": Call Email_Brazil
        Case "China": Call Email_China
        Case "France": Call Email_France            

    End Select

Next j    

End Sub
```

Like this you will always loop through all your cells and call your macros only if the country has been found. Moreover it will be straightforward adding/removing subs once you will need to do it.

Comment: The case call is exactly what I was looking for, how do I add the worksheet 'Info Table' into the range? The macro will be run from a different worksheet in the workbook.

Comment: I get a error at yourWorkbook = Workbooks("C:\Users\wb.xlsx"). Can I write something more like With this workbook , worksheet "Info Table"

Comment: Oh is it in the same workbook? Then look at the code now please

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have a separate sub for each country. I would use a single function to send all of your emails, like this:

```
Sub Send_Emails()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim country As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim message As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Info Table")
    Set country = ws.Range("D3:D30")

    ' loop through all cells in the range and email each
    For Each cell In country
        ' in case you need to pass something other than
        ' the country to the email function
        message = cell.Offset(, 2).Value2
        Call SendEmailTo(cell.Value2)
    Next cell

End Sub

Function SendEmailTo(country As String, message As String)
    ' rather than having a separate sub to send an email to each country
    ' use a function that accepts a country and send the email accordingly
    ' you now have access to both the country and
    ' the message (or modify to pass in whatever you need)

    ' The function should include boilerplate email code that all of the emails
    ' subs share, with a case statement for the parts that differ.
End Function
```

This will help keep your code DRY. ([Don't Repeat Yourself](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don't_Repeat_Yourself))

Comment: The problem is each email is different and not one generic one. It was easier for quality control to have the private subs so they can be updated for each country easily.

Comment: Is there any code copied over and over in the email subs? If so, you're better off having a function that includes the code that all of the subs share, and have your case statement inside the function for the parts that differ.